# WPF ComboBox horizontal scrollbar

Tags: wpf, combobox, scrollbar

I have a `ComboBox` with some large items and I would like to have a horizontal scrollbar. Is this possible?

Comment: Actually I can see an horizontal scrollbar by default in a combobox with large items. Could you post some code?

Comment: Do you mean a scrollbar when the combobox is 'dropped-down' or when only one item is visible?